Tkinter window crashes when I press the multiple choice button on my subtraction quiz
I created a graphical quiz. The Tkinter window crashes when I press the multiple choice button on the subtraction quiz. It doesn't crash on any other type of quiz. Sometimes it works when I click the multiple choice button, only to crash further into the quiz:
import tkinter as tk
import random

def main_menu():
    clear_window()
    root.configure(bg='DodgerBlue4')

    title = tk.Label(root, text="Math Quiz", font=("Arial", 32), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white')
    title.pack(pady=40)

    button_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='DodgerBlue4')
    button_frame.pack(pady=20)

    operations = [
        ("Multiplication", lambda: select_quiz_type('Multiplication'), 'red'),
        ("Addition", lambda: select_quiz_type('Addition'), 'forest green'),
        ("Subtraction", lambda: select_quiz_type('Subtraction'), 'blue'),
        ("Division", lambda: select_quiz_type('Division'), 'gold'),
    ]

    for operation, command1, color in operations:
        if command1:
            tk.Button(button_frame, text=operation, font=("Arial", 18), command=command1, bg=color, fg='white', width=12).pack(side='left', padx=20)


def clear_window():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

def select_quiz_type(operation):
    clear_window()
    root.configure(bg='DodgerBlue4')

    label = tk.Label(root, text=f"{operation} Quiz Type", font=("Arial", 24), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white')
    label.pack(pady=20)

    button_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='DodgerBlue4')
    button_frame.pack(pady=20)

    tk.Button(button_frame, text="Multiple Choice", font=("Arial", 18), command=lambda: start_quiz(operation, "multiple_choice"), bg='gold', fg='black').pack(side='left', padx=20)
    tk.Button(button_frame, text="Submit Box", font=("Arial", 18), command=lambda: start_quiz(operation, "submit_box"), bg='gold', fg='black').pack(side='left', padx=20)

def start_quiz(operation, quiz_type):
    if operation == "Multiplication":
        create_quiz("Multiplication", lambda: (random.randint(1, 12), random.randint(1, 12)), lambda x, y: x * y, quiz_type)
    elif operation == "Addition":
        create_quiz("Addition", lambda: (random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)), lambda x, y: x + y, quiz_type)
    elif operation == "Subtraction":
        create_quiz("Subtraction", lambda: (random.randint(0, 100), random.randint(0, 100)), lambda x, y: x - y, quiz_type)
    elif operation == "Division":
        create_quiz("Division", lambda: (random.randint(1, 100), random.randint(1, 10)), lambda x, y: x // y if y != 0 else 1, quiz_type)

def create_quiz(title, question_generator, answer_function, quiz_type):
    global current_operation, quiz_questions, quiz_answers, current_question, score, question_label, answer_buttons, answer_entry, current_quiz_type
    clear_window()

    current_operation = title.split()[0]
    current_quiz_type = quiz_type

    tk.Label(root, text=f"{title} Quiz", font=("Arial", 24), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white').pack(pady=20)

    quiz_questions = []
    quiz_answers = []

    for _ in range(10):
        x, y = question_generator()
        quiz_questions.append((x, y))
        quiz_answers.append(answer_function(x, y))

    current_question = 0
    score = 0

    question_label = tk.Label(root, font=("Arial", 18), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white')
    question_label.pack(pady=20)

    if quiz_type == "multiple_choice":
        answer_buttons = []
        for i in range(4):
            btn = tk.Button(root, font=("Arial", 18), bg='gold', fg='black', command=lambda control=i: check_mp_ans(control))
            btn.pack(pady=5)
            answer_buttons.append(btn)
    else:
        answer_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=("Arial", 18))
        answer_entry.pack(pady=10)
        tk.Button(root, text="Submit", font=("Arial", 18), command=check_sb_ans, bg='gold', fg='black').pack(pady=20)

    update_question()

def update_question():
    global current_question, quiz_questions, question_label, quiz_answers, current_quiz_type, answer_buttons
    if current_question < len(quiz_questions):
        x, y = quiz_questions[current_question]
        symbol = 'x' if current_operation == 'Multiplication' else '+' if current_operation == 'Addition' else '-' if current_operation == 'Subtraction' else '/'
        question_label.config(text=f"Question {current_question + 1}: {x} {symbol} {y} = ?")

        if current_quiz_type == "multiple_choice":
            correct_answer = quiz_answers[current_question]
            choices = [correct_answer]
            while len(choices) < 4:
                choice = random.randint(correct_answer - 10, correct_answer + 10)
                if choice not in choices and choice >= 0:
                    choices.append(choice)
            random.shuffle(choices)
            for i, choice in enumerate(choices):
                answer_buttons[i].config(text=str(choice))
    else:
        show_results()

def check_mp_ans(control):
    global current_question, score, quiz_answers
    selected_answer = int(answer_buttons[control].cget('text'))
    correct_answer = quiz_answers[current_question]
    if selected_answer == correct_answer:
        score += 1
        result_text = "Correct!"
    else:
        result_text = f"Wrong! The correct answer was {correct_answer}."

    current_question += 1
    show_answer_result(result_text)

def check_sb_ans():
    global current_question, score, quiz_answers, answer_entry
    try:
        user_answer = int(answer_entry.get())
    except ValueError:
        user_answer = None
    correct_answer = quiz_answers[current_question]
    if user_answer == correct_answer:
        score += 1
        result_text = "Correct!"
    else:
        result_text = f"Wrong! The correct answer was {correct_answer}."

    current_question += 1
    answer_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    show_answer_result(result_text)

def show_answer_result(result_text):
    clear_window()
    root.configure(bg='DodgerBlue4')

    tk.Label(root, text=result_text, font=("Arial", 24), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white').pack(pady=20)
    tk.Button(root, text="Next", font=("Arial", 18), command=recreate_question_interface, bg='gold', fg='black').pack(pady=20)

def recreate_question_interface():
    clear_window()
    global question_label, answer_buttons, answer_entry
    question_label = tk.Label(root, font=("Arial", 18), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white')
    question_label.pack(pady=20)
    if current_quiz_type == "multiple_choice":
        answer_buttons = []
        for i in range(4):
            btn = tk.Button(root, font=("Arial", 18), bg='gold', fg='black', command=lambda control=i: check_mp_ans(control))
            btn.pack(pady=5)
            answer_buttons.append(btn)
    else:
        answer_entry = tk.Entry(root, font=("Arial", 18))
        answer_entry.pack(pady=10)
        tk.Button(root, text="Submit", font=("Arial", 18), command=check_sb_ans, bg='gold', fg='black').pack(pady=20)
    update_question()

def show_results():
    global score, quiz_questions
    clear_window()
    root.configure(bg='DodgerBlue4')

    tk.Label(root, text="Quiz Complete!", font=("Arial", 24), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white').pack(pady=20)
    tk.Label(root, text=f"Your score: {score}/{len(quiz_questions)}", font=("Arial", 18), bg='DodgerBlue4', fg='white').pack(pady=10)
    tk.Button(root, text="Main Menu", font=("Arial", 18), command=main_menu, bg='gold', fg='black').pack(pady=20)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("900x600")
main_menu()
root.mainloop()

I tried it on two devices and it didn't work there too. The button grays out and the Tkinter window stops responding.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@Anish Patil. It worked for me when using Subtraction. Just run the script again.

The problem is an infinite loop in update_question(). It occurs precisely when the answer to the subtraction problem is less than -10. When this happens, the function can't generate answer choices between correct_answer-10 and correct_answer+10 that satisfy choice >= 0. This results in an infinite loop since len(choices) < 4 will always be true.
# If the answer is less than -10:
while len(choices) < 4: # Always true
    choice = random.randint(correct_answer - 10, correct_answer + 10) # Always < 0
    if choice not in choices and choice >= 0: # Always false
        choices.append(choice)

You have a few options for fixing this. One is to remove choice >= 0 entirely and allow for negative answers. If you still want to limit answers to non-negatives, you can add some code in your question generator to swap x and y when needed:
def create_quiz(...):
    ...

    for _ in range(10):
        x, y = question_generator()
        answer = answer_function(x, y)
        if answer < 0:
            x, y = y, x
        answer = answer_function(x, y)
        quiz_questions.append((x, y))
        quiz_answers.append(answer)

    ...

